# Messages.app (Mac) does not play sound when message received

Tags: audio, messages

Why does Messages.app on my Mac (Yosemite) fail to play a sound when a message is received?

On my Mac, I'm hearing sound from other apps. I hear a sound when I drag the "Output volume" in *System Preferences* > *Sound* > *Output*.

I hear the ding sound when messages simultaneously arrive on my iPhone and iPad.

In *Messages > Preferences > General > Message received sound* I have the popup set to "Note (Default)". Changing that popup does not help.

In *System Preferences > Notifications > Messages > Play sound for notifications* is checked. Unchecking and rechecking does not help.

The only odd thing, the only clue, is that in *System Preferences > Notifications > Messages* I found the *Messages alert style* icons had "None" selected but nonetheless have been seeing the *Alerts* style notifications appear upon new messages. Perhaps there is some kind of settings file not being updated, and needs to be trashed?

Comment: try a simple task first, use disk utility and repair permissions. try with logging in as different user to see if your user profile needs fixing.

Comment: What happens if your phone and iPad are off? My MacBook doesn't "ding" if my phone gets the message first.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I found that in System Preferences> Sound> Sound Effects:  The "Alert volume" was set at zero.  Adjusting it up solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I think I found what it was, for me at least.

System Preferences -> Sound Effects -> Play sound effects through: Internal Speakers

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a software program that somehow became my default sound program. I changed it back to internal speakers, and all is well.